# Why does __getattribute__ not work with some values?

Tags: python, class, oop, getattribute

my question is about `__getattribute__`. Please consider the following piece of code:

```
class Product():

  def __init__(self, name, quantity = 1, price =  0.0):
    self.name = name
    self.quantity = quantity
          self.price = price

  def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    if (attr == 'price'):
        return 30 * object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
       #change object.blala-la to the self.name or self.quantity 
    else:
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)

tmp = Product("Watermelon", 2, 50.0);
print(tmp.price)
```

I have found a bit misleading that if I change the `object.__getattribute__(self, attr)` to the `self.name` or `self.quantity` i will get 30 times string "Watermelon" or 60.0 (in case self.quantity), but if i put there `self.price` i will get `RuntimeError`, something about max recursion depth.

So, question: Why I cannot do that with `self.price` and just write instead `object.__getattribute__(self, attr)`?

Comment: What do you think `self.price` **does** when used in `__getattribute__`? `__getattribute__` is called for **all** attribute access, even for attribute access executed inside the same method. So `self.price` would call `__getattribute__` which accesses `self.price`, which calls `__getattribute__`, ad infinitum. Or until the runtime error.

Comment: Ok, i think i got it. `object.__getattribute__(self, attr(*price*))` works like a break statement for the endless accessing self.price. Is it correct?

Comment: No, you delegated to the original `object.__getattribute__` implementation. That implementation doesn't call `self.__getattribute__` so there is no recursion issue.

Comment: So, instead of typing `self.attr` we write `object.__getattribute__(self, attr)` in order to avoid infinite recursion, as it knocks to the __getattribute__ method definition in `object Class`, which interupts recursion? But if we will type something like, `return Product.__getattribute(self, attr)` or `return self.attr` in `if-else` then we will invoke next  recursion iterations?

Comment: Yes, because both would call `Product.__getattribute__` again. `self.attr` is the same thing as `type(self).__getattribute__(self, attr)`, and `type(self)` here is `Product`.

Answer (score 2):

The python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) says:

> `object.__getattribute__(self, name)`
>
> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an AttributeError.
>
> This method should return the (computed) attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception.
>
> **In order to avoid infinite recursion in this method, its implementation should always call the base class method with the same name to access any attributes it needs**, for example, **`object.__getattribute__(self, name)`**.